# How to display a DIV during a period of time? Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I have a query in Django that shows all the posts of the current user Ordered by the starting date of the post.

I want to display a `DIV` in the HTML template that says: `<div>“Will start soon”</div>` ,15 minutes before the Starting time of the post.

Does anybody knows in Javascript how can I display that HTML `div` During the last 15 minutes before the post starts?

I have two fields for making this script works:
Start_date and start_time

Thank you very much! Any idea is welcome!

```
<div class="publish-reminder invisibles" data-publish-time="{{ post.date_start }} {{ post.start_time }}">Will start soon</div>
```

```
for (let publishReminder of document.querySelectorAll("div.publish-reminder.invisibles")){
          setTimeout(function() {
              publishReminder.classList.remove("invisibles");
          },  new Date(publishReminder.getAttribute("data-publish-time") - new Date()));
     }
```

Comment: We'll be glad to help you out. But we do expect that you've at least made an attempt to create this. Include your code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to consider here:

## Hidden div

You could have a hidden `div` like

```
<div class="publish-reminder invisible" data-publish-time="2020-10-08 01:07:00"><!-- Some content here --></div>
```

And CSS

```
.invisible {
    display: none;
}
```

## HTML generation on server

Your server generates some HTML and you need to check on page load whether the post is to be published in less than 15 minutes. If the post is to be published in less than 15 minutes, then don't generate the `invisible` class into the `div`. Since this is a question that focuses on Javascript, I will not share much detail about server-side rendering.

## Client-side rendering

Let's do something like this:

```
for (let publishReminder of document.querySelectorAll("div.publis-reminder.invisible")) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        publishReminder.classList.remove("invisible");
    }, new Date(publishReminder.getAttribute("data-publish-time") - new Date()));
}
```

Explanation:

- we get all publish reminders which are (still invisible)
- we loop them
- we compute the time when they should be shown by subtracting the current date from the publish date and passing the resulting milliseconds as the second parameter of `setTimeout`
- in the callback we remove the `invisible` `class`

EDIT

After testing, I realized there are problems in the implementation. Here is a proof-of-concept:

```
function getDateString(dt) {
    return `${dt.getFullYear()}-${(dt.getMonth() + 1)}-${dt.getDate()} ${dt.getHours()}:${dt.getMinutes()}:${dt.getSeconds()}`;
}

var dateStrings = [];

var dt;
dt = new Date();
dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + 5);
dateStrings.push(getDateString(dt));
dt = new Date();
dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + 15);
dateStrings.push(getDateString(dt));
dt = new Date();
dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + 16);
dateStrings.push(getDateString(dt));
dt = new Date();
dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + 17);
dateStrings.push(getDateString(dt));

var divs = `
    <div class="publish-reminder invisible" data-publish-time="${dateStrings[0]}">First article</div>
    <div class="publish-reminder invisible" data-publish-time="${dateStrings[1]}">Second article</div>
    <div class="publish-reminder invisible" data-publish-time="${dateStrings[2]}">Third article</div>
    <div class="publish-reminder invisible" data-publish-time="${dateStrings[3]}">Fourth article</div>

`;

document.body.innerHTML += divs;

for (let publishReminder of document.querySelectorAll("div.publish-reminder.invisible")) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        publishReminder.classList.remove("invisible");
    }, ((new Date(publishReminder.getAttribute("data-publish-time"))) - (new Date())) - (15 * 60 * 1000));
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lp02h5u4/2/

Comment: Hi @Lajos Arpad thank you for your answer! I have edit the code in the question with your answer but is not working... the script is always removing the class and showing the message... Did i miss or forget something? thank you!!

Comment: @chrislumber you are welcome. You need to have the proper values in each of those divs for the attribute of data-publish-time.

Comment: @chrislumber you were right. There were problems in the implementation. Edited my answer, adding a tested proof-of-concept along with a link where you can test it.

Comment: You Rock!!!! The code is working!! But there is a bug that I found for future days... For example, if the post date is in the next year "2021-01-01 08:00:00", the function is removing the 'invisible' class... Do you know why is this happening?

Comment: @chrislumber happy to help. The bug is interesting. Apparently the number was just too large for setTimeout to properly handle it. I have added a safety measure, see https://jsfiddle.net/vokzL10y/

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeOut function it will display div after time given to it

```
setTimeout(function()

{

$('.publish-reminder').show();// or fade, css display however you'd like.

}, 5000);
```

it will display div after 5 seconds